# My Application is CPU intensive. C#

Tags: c#, memory, cpu

I have an application that loops an XML received from the live URL. The XML is received within few microseconds and then I process through loop.

My client says that application is very CPU intensive.

I am trying to know if I can reduce its CPU usage somehow? The application itself is no big, its just a big loop on the XML fields and regular if conditions..

```
foreach (XmlNode childNode in childNodes)
                {
                    if (childNode.Name == "update_status")
                    {
                        update_status = childNode.InnerText;
                    }

                    if (childNode.Name == "title")
                    {
                        title = childNode.InnerText;
                    }
```

Few lines from code above. There are many IF statements like this.

Comment: Please show more of your code, that little snippets doesn't give us anything helpful.

Comment: Rather than guess at it, why don't you simply use a profiler and see where the time is being using? http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/  (free 10-day trial)

Comment: Did you check for finding CPU intensive part (either using Trace and Stopwatch or a profiler)?

Comment: Are you sure that CPu time is spending to parse XML? According to the code you provided, I guess that CPU time leaks somewhere in different place

Comment: You can see code here: http://ecsbugtracker.com/demo1/feeds.txt

The functions which are being called like ADDCOUNTRY are data layer functions which ADD the data to the database.

Answer (score 3):

If your app is meant to be processing all the time, then of course it will consume all of the CPU. If it is meant to be waiting for new data to arrive, then it should not consume much CPU.

An incredibly common mistake that people make is to write a busy loop. That would look like this:

```
while (true)
    if (thereIsNewData())
        processNewData();
```

I'm going to make a wild guess that your code looks like this. This will run at full CPU utilization and spend almost all of its time repeatedly calling `thereIsNewData()` which would return `false` almost always.

What you need to do instead is to let the CPU idle when there is no data. And then wake-up to process it. There are countless ways to achieve that. In an ideal world you'd get a notification when there was new data. But if you can't manage that then polling with a sleep will throttle the CPU use.

Since we know nothing about the architecture of your application, I won't even attempt to suggest an implementation. But the key is that you use a blocking wait, rather than a busy loop.

Comment: I believe that the OP problem is probably something like this

Answer (score 0):

If it is always on the same model you can either assign to a dictionary

```
dico[childNode.Name] = childNode.InnerText;
```

or simply put everything in a  big switch case.

```
switch(childNode.Name)
{
  case "update_status": update_status = childNode.InnerText; break;
  case "title": title = childNode.InnerText; break;
  default: ...
}
```

In your code you systematically perform every `if` test, putting the remaining `if` into `else` blocks would slightly improve the performance if there are many of them.

A switch case would certainly be optimized away using a dictionary. See 
http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-switch

Anyway even with hundreds of if. It sounds surprising that this piece of code makes your client complains. Can you show us how you are handling the monitoring of your live url ?

Comment: There is no monitoring of URL. Its a single time read method, that loads the XML once. After that the code processes the XML.

Comment: @user1925139 Ok, and can you really observe the "intensive" CPU usage? Maybe it is only in the head of your client :)

Comment: he says that the application UPS usage is high. On my end, if I run it, it will take much memory like 1.40 GB constant memory..

Comment: whats UPS? and is the xml file huge?

Comment: sorry, its CPU not UPS. yes, XML file might be 10MB and sometimes, may be 100MB.